# Closing background form from foreground form in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have the following task .

Steps :

Form A opens form B on click of button

Expected :

Form B started and Form A closes .

Result :

Form B starts but Form A remains in the background .

I tried to solve the problem by passing a reference of the Form A to Form B but it strangely does not work .

In `Form A :( MainWindow)`

```
 AdminWindow window = new AdminWindow();
 window.setCreatingForm = this;
 window.Show();
```

In `Form B` : `(AdminWindow)`

```
public Window setCreatingForm
{
    get { return creatingForm; }
    set { creatingForm = value; }
}

public Window creatingForm { get; set; }

private void logOutClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (creatingForm != null)
        creatingForm.Close(); `// Why does this not close the background Form` 
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with WPF, but based on the one from Windows Forms, I think it would be easiest to close form A immediately after starting form B:

```
// form A code for launching B
AdminWindow window = new AdminWindow();
window.setCreatingForm = this;
window.Show();
this.Close();
```

The above should work because the method launching form B does not quit or block after the call to window.Show(). The call only blocks if a modal window is displayed (which in Widows Forms is done with window.ShowDialog()).

As for why the Close() in your code does not work, it looks like after destroying form A you are creating and showing a new form of the same type and maybe the original form is closed but what you are seeing is the newly created one.

**PS:** It is a bad practice to include set or get in the name of .Net properties. The set and get behavior are added by defining the set and get methods for the property. So in your code for AdminWindow the property for the creating form should be named `CreatingForm` instead of `setCreatingForm`.

Comment: Thanks i take your advice . I solved my problem by making use of the WPF Api "Hide" . So this.Hide() in wpf was what i was looking for . +1 for the help .

Comment: @rockstar, just note that closing and hiding are two different things. Closing not only removes the form from the UI, but also clears all resources associated with it. Hide does not perform the clearing part and usually you use hide when you need to reshow the same form instance (un-hide) at a later stage. If you are hiding a form and then creating a new one when showing it again you are wasting resources.

Answer (score 1):

Set the visible property of the parent form to false.

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
            this.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: This is for a normal WIndows form . I realised that there is no "Visible" attribute for a form in WPF . However i got your idea and found the equivalent attribute in WPF . Its called "Hide" so instead of this.Visible i need to do this.Hide . Thanks !